# Quotient of a local Cohen-Macaulay ring by a minimal prime

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring. Let $P$ be a minimal prime ideal of $R$.

Is it true that $\operatorname {depth} R/P=\operatorname {depth} R$ ?

Notice that since $R$ is local Cohen-Macaulay, so $\operatorname {depth}R=\dim R=\mathrm{ht}(P)+\dim R/P =\dim R/P$.

So basically I'm asking: Is $R/P$ again a Cohen-Macaulay ring ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is false and an example is given in Hartshorne's lecture notes, Ample subvarieties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on [Mohan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459133/quotient-of-a-local-cohen-macaulay-ring-by-a-minimal-prime#comment7111010_3459133), an example appears in Hartshorne's *[Ample subvarieties of algebraic varieties](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0067839),* Exercise 5.16 on p. 125. The exercise is worked out in Hartshorne's "[Complete intersections in characteristic $p > 0$](https://doi.org/10.2307/2373984)."

To clarify how this example is relevant, we summarize it here. Note that this example was mentioned before in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/140929/33088) by Hailong Dao.

**Example.** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p > 0$. Consider the monomial subalgebra
$$k[tu^3,t^3u,t^4,u^4] \subseteq k[t,u].$$
Hartshorne shows that the kernel $I$ of the surjective map $k[x,y,z,w] \twoheadrightarrow k[tu^3,t^3u,t^4,u^4]$ is generated *up to radical* by two elements $f$ and $g$. The ring $k[x,y,z,w]/(f,g)$ is Cohen–Macaulay since it is a complete intersection. On the other hand, its reduction (which is the quotient by the unique minimal prime) is $k[tu^3,t^3u,t^4,u^4]$, which is not Cohen–Macaulay (since the system of parameters $t^4,u^4$ is not a regular sequence).

To get a local example, just localize everything at the ideal $(x,y,z,w)$.

Comment: @uno Every reduced Noetherian ring of dimension one is Cohen–Macaulay (since reduced is equivalent to $(R_0)+(S_1)$). So I don't think one can construct a one-dimensional example.

Comment: Yeah never mind ... $R/P$ would be a domain of dimension $1$ so obviously CM ...